# "package does not exist" error building JUnit tests with Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, ant

I’m trying to execute unit tests using Ant. However, I am getting the error “package does not exist” even though I have included the classpath of the package.

**Folder Structure in Eclipse**

```
MyProject
  - src
    - com.project.core
      - MyApp.java
  - lib (contains all jar files and class files)

UnitTests
  -  src
    - com.project.core.tests
      - MyAppTest.java
  - lib (contains all jar files)
  - build.xml
```

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Learning TestNG" basedir="." default="build">

<property name="src.dir" value="C:/UnitTests/src/com/Project/core/tests/"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
<property name="src.jars" value="C:/MyProject/lib"/>
<property name="unit.test.jars" value="C:/UnitTests/lib"/>


<!--Define classpath  -->

<path id="master-classpath">

    <fileset dir="${src.jars}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <fileset dir="${unit.test.jars}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

</path>

<!--Print out path  -->

<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}|   |-- "             
            property="echo.path.compile"             
            refid="master-classpath">
</pathconvert>

<echo>${echo.path.compile}</echo>

<!-- Main Build  -->

<target name="build" description="Compile source tree java files">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>

    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.7" target="1.7" debug="on" includeantruntime="false" >
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
    </javac>
</target>
</project>
```

**Error**

```
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:/UnitTests/build
[javac] C:\MyProject\src\com\project\core\MyApp.java:14: error: package com.project.example does not exist
[javac] import com.project.example.AddNumbers;
```

I need to understand why I am getting this error when I am setting the the classpath to .class file correctly? I have tried everything. Perhaps this is an Ant issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `src.dir`

to 
`<property name="src.dir" value="C:/UnitTests/src"/>`

Source directory should start at the root of the packages.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, i am pointing it to a specific package which only contains one test case.The reason i'm doing this is because i have many tests and i first want to work with one test to see if i can solve the error.

Comment: Don't create a new source directory in package structure , if you need to separate them then create a directory at the root and put them in there.

Comment: I have tried this now, im still getting the same error

Comment: Please post the project directory structure that you have.

Comment: at the top of my post click on "Folder Structure in Eclipse"

Comment: Issue is that, there's an invalid import in the class `C:\MyProject\src\com\project\core\MyApp.java:14` for package `com.project.example.AddNumbers`. Do you have this package in the `classpath` ? It does not appear in your folder structure.

Comment: yes i do have it in my classpath which points to the .class file.